# HTML button link to open URL in the same tab is not working

Tags: html, url, button, page-refresh

I've created a HTML button in a WebPart which is configured as a Content Editor on a SharePoint Page.  When clicking on this button the URL is invoked and a new tab is opened successfully when I use the '_blank' switch.

However when I try to use the '_self' switch the tab just refreshes with the existing URL and does not open/invoke the new URL.  Any idea what I may be doing wrong.

I've removed all of my code and can re-create just with the below webpart HTML code:

```
**<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<body>
<button onclick="window.open('https://bbc.co.uk','_self')"> Link to BBC</button>
</body>**
```

I'm using Edge and Chrome and I get the same above problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem by just changing the current URL to the one you mention:

```
<body>
<button onclick="window.location.href=('https://bbc.co.uk')"> Link to BBC</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do It In a Simple Way**

```
<button onclick="location.href='https://github.com/AshirbadGudu'">
  Open My github
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daad, I used his solution as it worked.  No idea why my original code or the other two proposed solutions didn't work.